# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'image_data_format'

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have tried to run [my first demo](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py) using `keras` with `tensorflow` backend but failed:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mnist_cnn.py", line 26, in <module>
    if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'image_data_format'`

keras version: 1.2.1
tensorflow version: 1.0.1

How to fix?

Answer (score 2):

update `keras` to `2.0.2` and it fixed.